# What the relationship between Promises returned from chained .then() function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, chain

All:

I am pretty new to Promise, just curious how they get resolved, one thing confuse me is:

Some posts show using

```
var defer = $q.defer();

// some logic block
{
    // if success doing something
    defer.resolve();
}
return defer.promise;
```

But if use .then() function, promise is returned from .then(function(){}), I wonder how do I control if this promise resolved or not?

Another confuse is: If I use some chained .then() function, I wonder what is the relationship between them, are they same promise object which is just passed down or each .then will generate a new Promise object and return it?

Comment: > But if use .then() function, promise is returned from .then(function(){}), I wonder how do I control if this promise resolved or not?
Can you write example code for this?

Comment: @djechlin  var datapromise = $http.get("dataurl").then(function(data){ // here I do nothing}); How can I control the resolve of datapromise ?

Comment: could you explain yourself more clearly?

Comment: @FelipeSkinner var datapromise = $http.get("dataurl").then(function(data){ // here I do nothing}); How can I control the resolve of datapromise ?

Comment: besides, you cant control that. in this case $http.get("dataurl"); if you attach a "then" function there, it will be called whenever the promise is resolved by the anguler $http module. more or less like a callback

Comment: @FelipeSkinner Thanks, I wonder how can I control the datapromise returned from .then()?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in this throughout and clear [document](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/):

**QUESTION 1.** I wonder how do I control if this promise resolved or not?

One of the Promise APIs support pecial functions that `resolve()` or `reject()`  a Promise. So you may use the following functions in your code

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```

Rejections happen when a promise is explicitly rejected, but also implicitly 
if an error is thrown in the constructor callback.

```
var jsonPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // JSON.parse throws an error if you feed it some
  // invalid JSON, so this implicitly rejects:
  resolve(JSON.parse("This ain't JSON"));
});

jsonPromise.then(function(data) {
  // This never happens:
  console.log("It worked!", data);
}).catch(function(err) {
  // Instead, this happens:
  console.log("It failed!", err);
});
```

In other variants the Promise is resolved with the return value that is passed to the next link in the chain.

**QUESTION 2.**

Promises are in some sense functions that will result in the future with some value. The result value is the return value from promise - so basically promise chaining ( .then(...).then... ) are chain of functions that wait till the previous one will end ( resolve with some value ). Then they are called with an argument which is the return value of the last executed function in the queue ( previous link in the chain ).

`.then()` returns a new promise object thus allowing chaining. (see remark for documentation link)

**REMARK**

There is great and small description of all Angular promises in [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) under the section `Promise API` and next one - `Chaining the promises`.

Comment: All this while factually correct doesn't actually help OP with their question which is basically how then works in terms of chaining - which is by using return values and assuming the state of the promise returned from the `then` in async chaining.

Comment: `.then()` returns a new promise object thus allowing chaining.

Comment: The part that allows the actual chaining isn't then returning a new promise, it's that the return value of the `function` then takes (asynchronously) determines the state of the returned promise. Returning a new promise without this ability (for example, allowing just non-promise return values) would not allow chaining.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an attempt to explain promises in their full glory - there are blogs for that. This is to answer your specific questions:

**Q1:**

> But if I use `.then()` function, promise is returned from `.then(function(){})`, I wonder how do I control if this promise resolved or not?

The resolve handler function of `.then` controls how this promise is resolved:

1. If the handler function returns a non-promise value, then the promise with resolve with that value.

```
var thenPromise = originalPromise.then(function success() {
   return "foo";
});

thenPromise.then(function(data){
   console.log(data); // "foo"
});
```

2. If the handler function returns another promise, then the `.then` promise will resolve exactly how the new promise would resolve (or reject)

```
var thenPromise = originalPromise.then(function() {
   return $timeout(function(){ return "foo"; }, 1000);
});

thenPromise.then(function(data){
   console.log(data); // (after 1 second) "foo"
});
```

3. If the handler function throws an exception or if the the return is an explicitly rejected promise `$q.reject:

```
var thenPromise = originalPromise.then(function() {
   return $q.reject("some error");
});

thenPromise.then(function(data){
   console.log(data); // doesn't get here
})
.catch(function(err){
   console.log(err); // "some error"
});
```

**Q2:**

> If I use some chained `.then()` function, I wonder what is the relationship between them, are they same promise object which is just passed down or each `.then` will generate a new Promise object and return it?

Each `.then` generates its own promise.

```
var timeoutPromise = $timeout(afterTimeout, 1000);
var thenPromise = timeoutPromise.then(doSomething);
var anotherThenPromise = timeoutPromise.then(doSomethingElse);
```

If `timeoutPromise` resolves, then both `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` would execute and depending on their outcome `thenPromise` and `anotherThenPromise` would have their respective resolutions.